# When passing function as a parameter in python, how to specify only one parameter of the passed function

Tags: python

```
def func_a(func):
    return func(1)

def func_b(a, b=2):
    return a+b
```

Assuming there are 2 Python functions above. The func_a(func_b) will return 1 + 2 = 3. Is there any possible way that I can assign the value of parameter b when calling func_a, like func_a(func_b, b=3), so that I can change the default parameter 'b' of the called func_b, without adding an additional parameter to func_a.

Comment: Have a look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: @BrenBarn woo! It works, thank you!